# how to pass date parameter in odata url

Tags: java, web-services, rest, odata

For this input, i like to query only the date paramter and below is my URL

**http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$filter=StartsAt eq DateTime'2014-01-01T00:00:00'**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(sdkgbnxmswihlweriznxbilh))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People('russellwhyte')/Trips",
    "value": [
        {
            "TripId": 0,
            "ShareId": "9d9b2fa0-efbf-490e-a5e3-bac8f7d47354",
            "Description": "Trip from San Francisco to New York City. Nice trip with two friends. 
            "Name": "Trip in US",
            "Budget": 3000,
            "StartsAt": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "EndsAt": "2014-01-04T00:00:00Z",
            "Tags": [
                "Trip in New York",
                "business",
                "sightseeing"
            ]
        },
}
```

**But when i tried the query using date parameter i am getting the error. 
Kindly let me know whats the error in this query**

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: And what exact query with date parameter you use ?

Comment: Please refer to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047924/format-of-datetimeoffset-in-odata/28080733#28080733

Answer (score 0):

In latest .NetCore this format for DateTime is working perfect.

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$filter=StartsAt eq 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z
```