# Format of DateTimeOffset in OData

Tags: javascript, odata

I have two JavaScript `Date` objects. I need to do an OData query between these two `Date` objects. The information I'm querying has a field called `createDate` which is a `DateTimeOffset`. From my understanding, I can do something like this:

```
entities?filter=((createDate ge [Date1]) and (createDate le [Date2]))
```

My question is:

1. What format is a DateTimeOffset?
2. How do I convert a JavaScript Date object to DateTimeOffset format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First it depends your version of OData service. OData V4 is not compatible with OData V3.

**OData V4**

Format of DataTimeOffset please refer to [CSDL spec of OData V4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc406398065)

An example of filtering the DateTimeOffset is `http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')/Trips?$filter=StartsAt eq 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z`

**OData V3**

Format of DataTimeOffset please refer to [CSDL spec of OData V3](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/common-schema-definition-language-csdl/)

And example of filtering the DateTimeOffset is `http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=ReleaseDate gt datetime'1995-09-01T00:00:00'`